# Group time ranges by boolean values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Time Series with boolean values:

```
2014-09-09 08:01:07.617    False
2014-09-09 08:01:08.617    False
2014-09-09 08:01:09.616    False
2014-09-09 08:01:10.616    False
2014-09-09 08:01:11.617     True
2014-09-09 08:01:12.616     True
2014-09-09 08:01:13.616     True
2014-09-09 08:01:14.617     True
2014-09-09 08:01:15.616     True
2014-09-09 08:01:16.616     False
2014-09-09 08:01:17.616     False
2014-09-09 08:01:18.616     False
2014-09-09 08:01:20.116     False
2014-09-09 08:01:21.116     False
```

I want to calcluate the date range that have the same boolean values.
In the example above it would by

```
2014-09-09 08:01:07.617 -- 2014-09-09 08:01:10.616 False
2014-09-09 08:01:11.617 -- 2014-09-09 08:01:15.616 True
2014-09-09 08:01:16.616 -- 2014-09-09 08:01:21.116 False
```

The real data has 2e9 rows in the series. Is there any way to do this wihout iterating over the values of the series?

Comment: what are the name of your columns? (and do you have 2 or 3 columns?)

Comment: It is just a Serie, so there is only one column (and the index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `diff/cumsum` to assign a group number to the boolean values. 
Then groupby the group number, and use `.agg(['first', 'last'])` to obtain the first and last index in each group:

```
import pandas as pd

Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
ts = pd.Series({Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:07.617000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:08.617000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:09.616000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:10.616000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:11.617000'): True,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:12.616000'): True,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:13.616000'): True,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:14.617000'): True,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:15.616000'): True,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:16.616000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:17.616000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:18.616000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:20.116000'): False,
                Timestamp('2014-09-09 08:01:21.116000'): False})

df = ts.reset_index()
df['groupno'] = df[0].diff().cumsum().fillna(0)

result = df.groupby(['groupno'])['index'].agg(['first', 'last'])
print(result)
```

yields

```
                          first                    last
groupno                                                
0       2014-09-09 08:01:07.617 2014-09-09 08:01:10.616
1       2014-09-09 08:01:11.617 2014-09-09 08:01:15.616
2       2014-09-09 08:01:16.616 2014-09-09 08:01:21.116
```